# How to reduce the "free"-part-size of memory, which is shown in DDMS , in android development?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ddms, memory-optimization

Recently I was starting study how to optimize the memory usage in android development.

I was shocked when I used the "Update Heap" command in DDMS in eclipse to analyze the default Hello World application, which is created by clicking "New"→"Android Application Project" and just clicking "next" button without changing any configures until we finally click "finish", and I saw the heap size is over 13MB and the "free"-part-size which is shown in the table that next to the "Cause GC" button is 9MB!

Also in the table that shows below "Display:Stats" there is another "free"-part-size which is nearly 2MB.

The application is simple and I don't understand how it could consume over 10MB memory and what makes the "free"-part-size so large.

And how can we reduce the "free"-part-size in our development?

Looking forward to your answers. Thanks.